# Cant wake up after screen blacking

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, suspend, lock-screen

My computer seems to suspend when the screen timeout occurs, I can't move mouse to unlock it.

So when the screen goes blacking out, I cannot get to lock screen immediately, but had to wait around 10 minutes then when I move the mouse it goes to lock screen.

This is really bugging me, I use windows on the same computer it never happens so it cant be hardware issues.

Im using Lubuntu 18.04, is there anything I can do ? I heard about removing light-locker and replace it with xscreensaver, but apparently that also removes `lubuntu-desktop`, so I cant remove light-locker anyway.

Comment: Also when that happens I had to either reboot it or power it off altogether, I know the computer is still running.

Comment: Try waking the computer with either touching the space bar, or the power button.

Comment: Does not work, pressing power button immediately turn off the computer.